# Gradle Copy task only doing partial copy

Tags: java, gradle

I have a Gradle "deploy" task that copies a JAR and all the contents of a "config" folder to an intended destination. My project directory structure looks like:

```
myapp/
    src/main/java/
        <java sources>
    config/
        <lots of stuff>
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle
```

And my `deploy` task looks like:

```
task deploy(type: Copy, overwrite: true) {
    from('build/libs')
    into('/Users/myuser/myapp/deploy/myapp')
    include('myapp.jar')

    from('config')
    into('/Users/myuser/myapp/deploy/myapp')
    include('config/**')
}
```

When I run `./gradle build deploy`, I see the JAR getting copied to `/Users/myuser/myapp/deploy/myapp`, but **not** the `config` directory (nor all of its subdirectories and contents). The desired end result is a `/Users/myuser/myapp/deploy/myapp` directory that looks like:

```
/Users/myuser/myapp/deploy/myapp/
    myapp.jar
    config/
        <lots of stuff>
```

**Furthermore, the idea is that this copy should be "drop n' swap", particularly for the `config` directory.** That is, regardless of what is currently in the `/Users/myuser/myapp/deploy/myapp/config` directory, when I run `deploy`, those contents are *completely* replaced by whatever is in the `config/` directory of my project.

#### UPDATE

I have created a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/hotmeatballsoup/gradle-copy-example) to demonstrate the issue. Simply follow the instructions to reproduce.

Any ideas where I'm going awry?

Comment: updated my answer for your example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To directly answer your question:

  ```
  task deploy(type: Copy, overwrite: true){
      from ("$buildDir/libs"){include('gradlecopyexample.jar')}
      from ("$rootDir"){include('config/**')}
      into("$buildDir/deploy")
  }
  ```
- However, I still am of the opinion that the gradle application plugin is a good fit for your usecase. Instead of having the `config` folder in the root directory, place it under `src/dist`, Then running gradle `installDist` (or `distZip`) will include your config folder with the distribution package.

Comment: Thanks @RaGe but I am using the application plugin. Nothing about my post of Gradle snippet suggests otherwise! Once I have an executable JAR, I need to simulate a "deployment" by copying it and my config directory to a particular location.

Comment: Have you looked at the `installdist` task of the application plugin?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, the reason is `include('config/**')`, which should include something like `config/config/**`, where `**` is all subdirectories, but not all the files under `config/` directory.

Try to make it as follows:

```
task deploy(type: Copy, overwrite: true) {
    from('build/libs')
    into('/Users/myuser/myapp/deploy/myapp')
    include('myapp.jar')

    into('/Users/myuser/myapp/deploy/myapp')
    include('config/**')
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Stanislav, but this doesn't work. When I do a `ls -al /Users/myuser/myapp/deploy/myapp` I see the JAR having been copied there (with updated timestamp) but not the `config` directory.

Comment: @smeeb yep, updated an answer according to your layout. you have to delete the second `from` and copy it from the root, then it'tll copy the folder and everything within it. Just tested with Gradle 2.14.1

Comment: Thanks again @Stanislav (+1) - however this doesn't work for me. Please see my [Github repo](https://github.com/hotmeatballsoup/gradle-copy-example) that reproduces the problem perfectly. Only the JAR is copied, not the `config/` directory. Any ideas?